# Identifying order of integration

Tags: unit-root, structural-change

In Eviews ADF unit root test shows that variable is I(2), but unit root with structural breaks shows that variable is I(1). Can I conclude that variable is I(1)?

Answer (score 1):

> ...ADF unit root test shows that variable is I(2)...

This means that the ADF test is unable to reject the unit-root null for the first-differenced series, say $\Delta y_t$, but rejects for the twice-differenced series $\Delta^2 y_t$.

> ...unit root with structural breaks shows that is I(1)...

This means the Perron test (or whatever test you're using) is unable to reject the unit-root null for the series itself $y_t$, but rejects for $\Delta y_t$. (I am assuming that successive differencing is the procedure implemented in EViews. You should check documentation.)

> Can I coclude that variable is I(1)?

From purely mechanical considerations, yes.
The Perron test is designed to have power against alternatives which are stationary but has structural break. So these results suggest $\Delta y_t$ is possibly stationary but with structural break, and the ADF test mistakenly took this as unit root.

Without knowing more about your data, that's all one can say.
Ideally, you should be able to explain why $\Delta y_t$ is possibly stationary but with structural break, with more than purely statistical results.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It is exchange rate series. There is a regime shift in monetary policy, therefore it has a structural break.

Comment: @PHPUseless I see. Structural breaks in exchange series are almost always identifiable as due to change in monetary policy.